# Sitecore field value is not updated during deploy

Tags: deployment, sitecore, tds

I'm having problem with deploying changes to Sitecore item. I've made changes in the template item in Sitecore. All changes of Sitecore items are stored in TDS. During the build TDS generates an update package, then I install this package using Sitecore UpdateInstallationWizard during deployment.

The problem is that I've already deployed several builds, and just found out that changes are not applied to this template item: I've removed one field from the item, but it still appears, also I've changed another field value in the _Standard Values but it does not change after deployment.

Could you please help me to find the cause of this issue? Is there any way to review what items are in the package?

UPD: I've renamed package into zip and was able to find the template item itself and standard values for the item in the addeditems folder. As I understand it right it should mean that the item with all the changes is in package, but for some reason they are not applied.

Answer (score 2):

By default, TDS will NOT remove anything from Sitecore. You need to setup the child item synchronization settings and enable removing/recycling items in the build property page for the target environment. Please see:

http://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter4.html#deployment-properties
http://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter4.html#build
http://www.hhogdev.com/help/tds/deploymentproperties

For more information. I recommend that you use the deployment property manager window to make sure your templates are set to "Always". Tell TDS to put items in the recycle bin in the build property page and backup your target database before trying this for the first time. Once you get the hang of the deployment properties, it is pretty easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You can review the actions applied from an .update package within the update installation wizard itself, right after applying the package. Click the button labeled "Installation result>" and try filtering the list to look for warnings and errors related to your item.

Another option is to review logs located at ~/temp/__UpgradeHistory/ folder. In particular, I would look at the messages.xml file.